# How to use estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath with async func? swift

Tags: ios, swift, cell

I'm moving and app I had on Parse to Firebase and I ran into an issue with a cell that needs to get resized.It contains a textview that recieves data, since the text varies in size, I am using this two methods:

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

With Parse this worked perfectly because I would recieve the entire object that I had to pass to the DetailTableView in the MainTableView. With Firebase, I handle it differently, I retrieve what the MainTableView needs, then I just pass a reference to the DetailTableView and again retrieve whatever I need there. The problem seems to be that the size of the cell gets set before the async function can set the text. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to reload your table view (or specific cell) after you get whole data.

Comment: Duh! according to me I tried that but apparently I put it in the wrong place  because it worked this time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can wrap the code setting the text on the cell with calls to `tableView.beginUpdates()`
`tableView.endUpdates()`